# Bash script redirection not working as a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a readonly variable set in a bashscript:

```
readonly NO_OUTPUT="1>/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Why is it, when I use this variable with certain commands in the script, it gives an error like it's thinking that ${NO_OUTPUT} is another file in its list?

For example, I have the following:

```
make install ${MAKE_PREFIX} ${NO_OUTPUT}
```

generates an error at the end that says:  `make: *** No rule to make target '1>/dev/null 2>&1'.  Stop.`

However, if I change it to:

```
make install ${MAKE_PREFIX} 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

it works exactly as expected?

I have similar issues with other commands (cp, rm, etc) where it errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
make install ${MAKE_PREFIX} ${NO_OUTPUT}
```

Calls `make` with `install`, the result of split+glob applied to the contents of the MAKE_PREFIX variable and the result of split+glob applied to the contents of the NO_OUTPUT variable as separate arguments.

Probably you want something like:

```
if [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]; then
  nooutput() { "$@"; }
else
  nooutput() { "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1; }
fi

nooutput make install "$MAKE_PREFIX"
```

For `make` to be called with `install` and the contents of the MAKE_PREFIX variable as separate arguments, and its stdout and stderr redirected to /dev/null if not run in verbose mode.

You could also use aliases here:

```
if [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]; then
  alias nooutput=' '
else
  alias nooutput='> /dev/null 2>&1 '
fi

nooutput make install "$MAKE_PREFIX"
```

Though beware if using the `bash` shell not in POSIX mode, you need `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

The alias also needs to have been defined at the time the code using it was **read** (not *run*).

In `zsh`, you can also have *global* aliases that are expanded even when not in command position, so you could do:

```
if [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]; then
  alias -g '$NOOUTPUT$='
else
  alias -g '$NOOUTPUT$=> /dev/null 2>&1'
fi

make install "$MAKE_PREFIX" $NOOUTPUT$
```

Here using `$NOOUTPUT$` instead of `$NOOUTPUT` to make it clearer that no parameter expansion is happening there, the `$NOOUTPUT$` is being replaced with either nothing or `> /dev/null 2>&1` when the code is being read, long before it is being evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The shell separates each word (token, part) on the command line to identify what each part is a long time before expanding each part. Redirections are set-up close to that command line parsing phase. The variable expansion at the much later time becomes only **one** word which could not become a redirection.

No, not even array variables, or simple variables could work:

```
$ NO_OUTPUT=( "1>/dev/null"    "2>&1" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${NO_OUTPUT[@]}"
1>/dev/null
2>&1

$ a="1>/dev/null"
$ b="2>&1"
$ printf '%s\n' "$a" "$b"
1>/dev/null
2>&1

$ printf '%s\n' 1>/dev/null 2>&1

$
```

So, no, there is no way to convert variable contents to shell word tokens.

Except `eval`. But eval is usually `evil`. A security risk.

Answer (score 1):

use `eval` command, it takes a string and runs it as a command, your code should look like this:

```
eval make install ${MAKE_PREFIX} ${NO_OUTPUT}
```

on why it happens and also some better ways to get the result you want take a look at [How can we run a command stored in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable).

Comment: Should rather be: `eval 'make install "$MAKE_PREFIX" '"$NO_OUTPUT"`. i.e., you don't want the expansion of `$MAKE_PREFIX` to be passed to `eval`, and you don't want either of these variables to be subject to split+glob. You want `eval` to evaluated the `make install "$MAKE_PREFIX" > /dev/null 2>&1` shell code.